# Using <audio> element for playback of raw audio

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I'm working on a little project that decrypts (using openpgp.js) and decodes a server-side audio file using the Web Audio API. The decrypted file arrives to the client as raw audio. Currently I can play back audio files using `source.start(0)` but there doesn't seems to be an easy way to dump the audio to a GUI that would allow users to do things like adjust volume and seek through the audio.

I have a `AudioContext` object that's decoded and buffered with `createBufferSource`

```
function playSound(decodedAudio) {
  var source = context.createBufferSource();
  source.buffer = decodedAudio;
  source.connect(context.destination);
  source.start(0);
}
```

Because it's raw audio being received I can't simple use something like `audio.src = ...` with an audio element. Or maybe I'm overlooking something obvious?
Is there a way to have this decoded audio within the Web Audio API play nicely with a destination `<audio>` element?

**The ideal flow would look something like...**
1) User clicks to engage the playback of an audio clip
2) The audio is decrypted server side and sent to the client as a raw audio
3) The audio is decoded and playable, seekable...etc.

**Possible solutions that I'd love thoughts on**
- Because the audio files can range anywhere from 1 minute to 60 minutes, write the audio to a file using the FileSystem API and then use an `<audio>` element for actual playback
- Write my own control system for pausing, scrubbing, and volume on top of the Web Audio API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice question! The simplest solution would be storing the decoded content in a [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob).

That would allow you to set the `src` attribute.

```
var blob = new Blob(decodedData, {type: "correct-mimetype/here"});
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
audio.src = url;
```

Comment: Would it be more efficient to create a blob for each packet or the entire clip?

Comment: That depends on the goal, or how the data is sent from the client (what protocol? HTTP? WS? WebRTC? That changes depending on what OP wants really, and if partial data helps.

Comment: Maybe WebSockets (this is all theoretical, I'm just thinking about doing a VoIP typing thing, but I have a feeling blobs have large overhead...)

Comment: Blobs do have a large overhead in these cases, especially given the alternatives. Honestly I'd probably just use the built in security of HTTPS instead of [rolling out my own crypto](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2202/lessons-learned-and-misconceptions-regarding-encryption-and-cryptology/2210#2210). That would allow me to use set the .src myself, or use a well known and tested challenge-response mechanism to generate a url for the .src attribute for the client and send it from the server when the client has authenticated.